# newsletter shadow making 100% height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am busy with a newsletter and background images won't work in newsletters so i trying to fix this with 1px borders. The top and bottom shadows are working fine but i can not get the left and right sides at 100% height so maybe can somewone help with this?

This is the Fiddle with i now have: [click here for the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tszuf/)

HTML:

```
 <table width="702" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
           <td width="72" valign="top"><img src="logo-ro.png" alt="" /></td>
           <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                <div style="border-top : 1px solid #e3e8ec;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e3eaf2;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e1eaf3;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e1eaf1;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e2ebf2;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e2ebf2;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e4ebf3;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e7ebf4;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e8ecf5;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e9edf6;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #eaedf6;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #ecf1f7;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #ecf1f7;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #edf2f6;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #eff2f7;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #f1f5f8;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #f4f5f9;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #f5f6f8;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #f6f6f8;"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
           </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td width="19" valign="top">
                <div style="border-left : 1px solid #e3e8ec;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #e3eaf2;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #e1eaf3;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #e1eaf1;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #e2ebf2;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #e2ebf2;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #e4ebf3;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #e7ebf4;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #e8ecf5;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #e9edf6;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #eaedf6;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #ecf1f7;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #ecf1f7;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #edf2f6;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #eff2f7;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #f1f5f8;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #f4f5f9;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #f5f6f8;"><div style="border-left : 1px solid #f6f6f8;"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
           </td>
           <td valign="top">fdsfsfsdf</td>
           <td width="19" valign="top">
                <div style="border-right : 1px solid #e3e8ec;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #e3eaf2;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #e1eaf3;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #e1eaf1;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #e2ebf2;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #e2ebf2;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #e4ebf3;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #e7ebf4;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #e8ecf5;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #e9edf6;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #eaedf6;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #ecf1f7;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #ecf1f7;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #edf2f6;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #eff2f7;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #f1f5f8;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #f4f5f9;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #f5f6f8;"><div style="border-right : 1px solid #f6f6f8;"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
           </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                <div style="border-top : 1px solid #f6f6f8;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #f5f6f8;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #f4f5f9;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #f1f5f8;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #eff2f7;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #edf2f6;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #ecf1f7;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #ecf1f7;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #eaedf6;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e9edf6;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e8ecf5;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e7ebf4;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e4ebf3;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e2ebf2;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e2ebf2;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e1eaf1;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e1eaf3;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e3eaf2;"><div style="border-top : 1px solid #e3e8ec;"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
           </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: `</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>` **Divfalls**

Comment: can you show mw what kind of design u need ??? what you have done is wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving some height to the innermost div in left and right hierarchy of divs.

```
<div style="border-left : 1px solid #f6f6f8; height: 100px;"></div>
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z4DFy/

Answer (score -1):

Abandon this approach immediately.

Instead, use CSS `box-shadow` (**[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tszuf/1/)**).

E.g.

```
box-shadow: 0 0 28px 14px #E3EAF2 inset;
```

This property has 6 parameters:

- left offset
- top offset
- blur
- spread (optional - *0* by default)
- color
- *inset* (optional)

Comment: This is for mail html and most clients won't support box-shadow